# How to find previous nonblank spreadsheet row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a formula to find the most recent nonblank row, to compute some additional statistics on.  My spreadsheet is going to look something like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 |  |  |
| 4 | 4 | 9 |  |  |
| 5 | 5 | 11 |  |  |
| 6 | 6 | 13 | 4 | 8 |
| 7 | 7 | 15 |  |  |

For example, for the formula in cell C6, I want it to discover that the most recent row with data in column C was row 2, and make a computation based on that.  I will *not* know, in advance, how many blank rows there are in between.

It looks like the `XMATCH` function would do just what I want, but that appears to be Office 365 only.  I'm using Excel 2016 for Mac, and I'd like my spreadsheet to be portable to Excel versions of that vintage.

Willing to use VBA if I have to, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a `LOOKUP`, like this:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(C1:C6<>""),C1:C6)
```

Another method (way less clean, but it works...):

```
=INDIRECT("C"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C1:C5)*(C1:C5<>""))))
```

Those will return you the value of C2 (in this case.)

Comment: Oh, my goodness.  No, not exactly "clean", but you're right, it works!  If nothing better turns up, I guess this'll be my solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I added a better option